# Uninstall Ubuntu from dual boot

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, hard-disk

I have my laptop dual booted with Windows in basic drive (ssd) and ubuntu in dynamic drive(hdd) but now I wish to uninstall ubuntu. I followed some steps as they were given online:

1) In disk management in window I deleted partition where I had installed ubuntu.
2) I tried extending existing hdd partition to unallocated space but couldn't because of the error message: " There is not enough space available on disk(s) to complete this action "

Please help me out with this.

Finally:
[image]
Also, I am unaware of where that primary partition of 7.63 GB came from because as far as I remember I had partitioned my drive to create a 100 GB partition for ubuntu.

[image: This is the present disk management state of my laptop]

[image: Edit: I have removed boot for ubuntu now but scenario still remains the same]

Also, as per suggestion in the comment, I tried to switch to Basic disk from dynamic but the option isn't available as is shown in second picture.

Please help!

Further Update:
I have been able to recover the E drive partition by extending D but still the problem with remaining two partition including swap folder remains.

I think that converting to basic should work but I fear deleting existing volume although I have backed up data. I fear that I might not be able to create any partition out of the unallocated space and what if it doesn't change to basic even then. Also, I am not able to delete the swap volume in first place but diskart doesn't display that, I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: You might have swap partition? Even if only using Windows better not to use dynamic. With newer gpt partitioning there is no real reason for dynamic. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv
Since UEFI, you can remove ubuntu entry in UEFI and /EFI/ubuntu folder. Or did you install in BIOS mode to sdb drive? Uninstall Ubuntu UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Comment: I have uninstalled ubuntu UEFI boot menu. But still I am not able to use the unallocated memory.    Moreover, as given in Microsoft docs, I tried to convert logical volume to  primary volume and so deleted partition D after backing up data but now even that is being shown as unallocated and I am not able to use it.

Comment: @oldfred please help! I have edited the question now to include the updates I have done on the basis of your suggestions. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I finally got through by using diskpart to format the disk after backing up data and then intializing it. Thanks a lot btw @oldfred

Comment: Since first drive is gpt, did you make second drive gpt? Once you start using UEFI, you should use gpt for all drives.

Comment: @SAGALPREETSINGH would you like to self-answer this question with the steps you took, or should we close it since you no longer have the issue? Thank you!